# SQL Update a Single Row Multiple Times (Row by Row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm working in tsql and have an issue where I need to do multiple updates to a single row based on multiple conditions.

1. By Rank in ascending order
2. If the column is NULL I need it to update no matter what the Rank is.
3. If the Ranks are the same I need it to update in order of T2_ID.
4. And I need it to use the last updated output.

I've tried using the update statement below but it only does the first update and the rest are ignored. Here is an example of the data sets I'm working with and the desired results.

Thanks in advance!

```
update a
set Middle = case when a.Rank_ >= b.Rank_ OR a.Middle IS NULL then ISNULL(b.Middle, a.Middle) end,
    LName = case when a.Rank_ >= b.Rank_ OR a.Lname IS NULL then ISNULL(b.LName, a.LName) end,
    Rank_ = case when a.Rank_ >= b.Rank_ then b.Rank_ end
from #temp1 a
inner join #temp2 b on a.fname = b.fname
where 
    b.T2_ID in (select top 100% T2_ID from #temp2 order by T2_ID asc)
```

**TABLE1**:

```
Fname   Middle  Lname   Rank_
------------------------------
John    NULL    NULL    2
```

**Table2**:

```
 T2_ID  Fname   Middle  Lname   Rank_
 --------------------------------------
    1   John    Mike    Doe      3
    2   John    NULL    Smith    1
    3   John    NULL    Davis    1
```

Desired result:

```
Fname   Middle  Lname   Rank_
-------------------------------
John    Mike    Davis   1
```

Comment: I did not understand the rules to update Rank_ column. Could you clarify?

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do it using a CTE?  I did Try it an I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: I also Updated the Rank_ Rule but esentially if a rcd has a Lower value than the rcd being updated, than update the field, else ignore.

Comment: Your join returns more than one line for each row in `#table1`. UPDATE must uniquely determine what data should be updated.

Comment: I dont see how the Rank_ for John Mike Davis change from 2 to 1. Explain it, please.

Comment: Sorry Thiago, you were right.  I corrected the Case Statement to a.Rank_>=b.Rank

Answer (score 2):

A single UPDATE statement can only update each record once.

So if I understand you correctly, the result you want is simply one record per Fname, using the non-null values for each column with the lowest rank and in case of ties, the highest T2_ID?

You could achieve this simply using subselects:

```
SELECT 
    Fname,

    (SELECT TOP 1 Middle FROM #temp1 b
     WHERE Middle IS NOT NULL AND b.Fname = a.Fname
     ORDER BY Rank_, T2_ID DESC) AS Middle

    (SELECT TOP 1 Lname FROM #temp1 b
     WHERE Lname IS NOT NULL AND b.Fname = a.Fname
     ORDER BY Rank_, T2_ID DESC) AS Lname

    (SELECT TOP 1 Rank_ FROM #temp1 b
     WHERE Rank_ IS NOT NULL AND b.Fname = a.Fname
     ORDER BY Rank_, T2_ID DESC) AS Rank_
FROM
    #temp1 a
GROUP BY
    Fname    /* To get one record per Fname */
```

You can then update `#temp2` using the result of this select.

Comment: I understand the logic on this query but it can't possibly be an efficient way to do this.  In my actual query i'm updating ~10 columns.  This method would be way too heavy on a db

Comment: You should try it out, before making any assumptions on the performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
You also user group by and having 



    create table #temp1(

    fname varchar(10),
    mname varchar(10),
    lname varchar(10),
    rank_ int
)
 create table #temp2(
    t2id int,
    fname varchar(10),
    mname varchar(10),
    lname varchar(10),
    rank_ int
)

insert into #temp1
select 'john',null,null,2 

insert into #temp2
select 1,'john','mike','doe',3 union all 
select 2,'john',null,'smith',1 union all 
select 3,'john',null,'davis',1 


select top 1 fname,(select top 1 mname from #temp2 order by rank_ desc) as mname,lname,min(asrank_) from (
select b.rank_,a.fname,case when a.Rank_ >= b.Rank_ OR a.mname IS NULL then ISNULL(b.mname, a.mname) end as mname,
    case when a.Rank_ >= b.Rank_ OR a.Lname IS NULL then b.LName end as lname,
    case when a.Rank_ >= b.Rank_ then b.Rank_ end asrank_
from #temp1 a
inner join #temp2 b on a.fname = b.fname)tbl group by fname,mname,lname having min(asrank_)=1



drop table #temp2
drop table #temp1
```